# Where can I find a consolidated list of the SQL Server Format Strings that the FORMAT Function Accepts

Tags: sql-server, formatting

I can't seem to find a complete list of all the available options the *format* parameter accepts within the FORMAT function.  Outside of random google searches that take me to pages specific to either Dates or Currency I have yet to find a link to a consolidated list.

As an example of what I'm after I know that the FORMAT function accepts 'D' for Date, 'C' for Currency, 'N' for number.

From another random google search I found that I could use 'C0' or 'C1' to specify how many decimals I want but again... I didn't find this on any 'LIST' and I didn't see this on any official Microsoft site.

[image]

**Example Screenshot of the FORMAT Function:**
[image]

Comment: Personally I would suggest avoiding `FORMAT`, it's an awfully slow function. Use the Style codes and `CONVERT` if you must, but otherwise leave the format of the values to your presentation layer.

Comment: ^^^^ YES THIS!!! ^^^^^

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you will find that the formatting uses dotnet formatting. Then you will find the link to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN). This is extremely well documented and it is more complex than a "LIST" can provide.

Comment: @Larnu ha Yes... I did see some links that mentioned the slowness in using the FORMAT function.  The issue I'm faced with is that the SQL in the application I support is what is used in some cases as the Presentation Layer.  Nice to know though that I should use something else however a list would still be nice :)

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you.  I did find that link and you are correct that documentation isn't as easy as a 'LIST'.  I suppose after seeing links like the below I became spoiled as it's a really nice list showing off FORMAT's Date and other options.  https://database.guide/standard-numeric-format-strings-supported-by-format-in-sql-server/

Comment: Honestly I don't know how much clearer or simple it could be. Follow the second link in my first comment. Then look on the left hand navigation pane. It provides links to groups of formatting options. Each page has a list with lots of explanation about all the options for each type.

Comment: @SeanLange Very true.  I believe this is what I was looking for but overlooked.  Thank you much.  This link is actually the 2nd option under the 'Formatting Types' listed in the left hand navigation pane.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: There is no complete list.  This is limited to you imagination and requirements (within reason),  Just for fun, try select format(1125,'00-00-00') or even Select format(getdate(),'dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt')